# focus an element created on the fly

Tags: javascript, dom

how to focus an element created on the fly?

Answer (score 8):

Just call [`.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) on the element after it's added to the DOM, for example:

```
var input = document.createElement("input"); //create it
document.body.appendChild(input);            //append it
input.focus();                               //focus it
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mF2b3/4/).

Comment: ... which works so long as the element created is one capable of receiving the focus.

Answer (score 4):

The [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) method will do this.  If you have a reference to the newly-created element called `elem`, then simply invoke:

```
elem.focus();
```

Note that you'll need to do this *after* inserting the element into the document at the appropriate point, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
var txtObj = document.createElement("input");
window.document.body.appendChild(a);
txtObj.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
  $('#container').append('<input type="text">');
  $('#container').find('input:last').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: What if there is more than one `input` in `#container`?

Comment: You can add id or class to the input. Or can do :last. I will update the answer with :last

Answer (score -2):

> You can use setTImeOut

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#id_of_element_created").focus().select();
       }, 100);
```