# Keyboard focus for flash on all browsers

Tags: javascript, swfobject

How would be the code to set keyboard focus for swf on other browsers (not IE).

I know that for IE is just

```
document.getElementById('movieID').focus();
```

How would be for other browsers?

Comment: your code is fine, please make further investigations to your code and search more thoroughly on the forum before posting such questions. anyway check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183325/focus-an-element-created-on-the-fly), a possible duplicate.

Comment: I think that only works for IE. 
Doesn´t work for Chrome.

Comment: That thread may give focus to flash but doesn´t gives keyboard focus to flash.

Answer (score 2):

The only HTML elements that natively support focus are links (`<a>`) and form elements, such a `<input>`. To make an HTML element focusable via javascript, you need to set the element's `tabIndex`.

(Jonathan Snook wrote a [nice simple overview](http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex) a few years back. [Mozilla provides a good overview of the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets), and the W3C discusses [keyboard focus in relation to ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-implementation/#keyboard-focus_tabindex).)

Once the Flash SWF is embedded, you can focus the new `<object>` element like so:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var callbackFn = function(e){
   if(e.success){
      e.ref.tabIndex = "-1";
      e.ref.focus();
   }
};

swfobject.embedSWF("myfile.swf", "myflashelement", "550", "400", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, callbackFn);
```

Keyboard focus is discussed in depth in this [SWFObject support thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/swfobject/IyYeoofq4mE/discussion) if you'd like more information.

Comment: Place the code within the script tag? And use 'myflashelement' as embed id, and myfile.swf as the src?

Comment: what is 'expressInstall.swf'?

Comment: Do I need to set params.wmode = 'opaque'?

Comment: opaque is probably a good idea for best cross browser support. re: how to use swfobject, please refer to the swfobject documentation